# Transforming a dataframe in spark scala

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a dataframe (df) of the following form:

```
+-----+-----   +
|id   |items   |
+-----+-----   +
|   0 |  item1 |
|   1 |  item2 |
+-----+-----   +
```

Here first column id is an int and second column items is of type struct.
Lets say item is as shown:

```
     item1
        |-a
        |-b
        |-c
        |-d
```

I want the resultant table of the form

```
   +-----+-----   +
   |id   |col2   |
   +-----+-----   +
   |   0 |  a    |
   |   0 |  b    |
   |   0 |  c    |
   |   0 |  d    |
   |   1 |  a    |
   |   1 |  b    |
   |   1 |  c    |
   |   1 |  d    |
   +-----+-----   +
```

I want to expand struct for every column?
How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This peice of code may solve your problem:

```
df.rdd.flatMap{row=>
val id=row.getInt(0)
val arrayOfString=row.getAs[Array[String]](1)
arrayOfString.map(value=>(id,value)
}.toDF("id","col2")
```

Note: this code is not tested !

Comment: In this the type of column "items" is struct . How can it be type casted to array[string]

Comment: Then remove the array[String] part and put your own value in which you want to take out